# how to fetch componentPresentation from brokerdb?

Tags: tridion, tridion-content-delivery

I am new to SDL Tridion,just exploring content delivery.
I used below code in the TBB of my pagetemplate

```
<% ComponentPresentationFactory factory = new ComponentPresentationFactory("tcm:0-6-    1");
ComponentPresentation ps = factory.GetComponentPresentationFactory("tcm:6-9841","tcm:6-9858-32");
if(ps!=null )
{
 string output="";
   output=ps.Content;
   Literal1.Text=output;
 }
 %>
  <asp:Literal id="Literal1"Text="" runat="server"<</asp:Literal>
```

I have published that component and used a dynamic component template.
But no content is reflecting on the page.Did i missed something?

Comment: Hi, am i mistaken or does your question have nothing to do with `Simple DirectMedia Layer (SDL)` as is tagged with `SDL` ? Also please clarify what language you are using.

Comment: Also, you may want to use the Tridion-dedicated stacked exchange site on http://tridion.stackexchange.com for your Tridion questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the whitespace from the uri tcm:0-6-1 and your code should read `factory.GetComponentPresentation("tcm:6-9841","tcm:6-9858-32");`

Comment: Also check the typo in the asp:Literal control at the end--it doesn't close properly.

Comment: found out the reason for this,there was mismatch with the publication ID that i was passing.